# How can I use Stackage's cabal.config files with nix-style cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, stackage, cabal-new

Stackage provides a `cabal.config` file with each snapshot, e.g. [this one](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.9/cabal.config). How can I make cabal `new-configure` a project with the package versions from that file?

(Alternatively: Is there another way to configure a nix-style cabal project with dependency versions from a specific Stackage snapshot?)

Answer (score 2):

The `cabal.config` files from Stackage only contain a single huge `constraints` section with the same syntax that the `cabal.project` files use.

So you can simply copy these constraints into your `cabal.project.local` file, delete any constraints for packages in your local project and `new-build`.